# How to unfollow twitter followers the dont follow back twitter

Tags: javascript, twitter

I want to unfollow some of the twitter accounts i follow that dont follow back without unfollowing the accounts that follow me back due to reaching my limit? I tried this code but it unfollows all:

```
$('.button-text.unfollow-text').trigger('click’);
```

I have been doing this via the javascript console

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In your browser developer window (F12 or F11), paste this.

Caution - it will click the Unfollow button of everyone on the page.  you might need to filter or sort to keep the ones you want.

```
$.each($(".user-actions-follow-button"), function( index, value ) { value.click() });
```

Comment: Hi Friend, thanks for your help. I have the code that bulk deletes people i follow, im looking to some how filter the people i follow that dont follow me back through the code and bulk unfollow that group

Comment: have you find any script. then put it in answer @ryan